# How can i have horizontal listView or gridView with manual control

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, gridview, android-gallery

[image]I'm working on an application that need some thing like old [Gallery](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html), but it doesn't need to be scrollable... Instead it should be working with two control element imageButtons ,as you can see in picture, which are used to smothscroll to next or previous position. I created a gridView in my XML:

```
            <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView2"
            android:background="#E4E4E4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="12"
            android:stretchMode="none"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp" >
        </GridView>
```

But smoothScrollToPosition method only change row, not columns. I mean if I have 30 element in this grid, it won't do anything in first 12 step (numColumns="12") then in 13 it smoothly scroll to next row.
linearView and bunch of Images would work just fine, but linearView has no method to change position of its childs, like smoothScrollToPosition do to listView and gridView
Thanks...

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view it's exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you can solve it with [HorizontalScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)
use smoothScrollTo or other available functions to scroll